# unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

```
def radiance(l,T):
    l=l*(10**(-10))
    const=2*h*pi*(c**2)
    const2=(h*c)/(k*T)
    d=expo(const2/l)-1
    f=const/(d*(l**5))
    return f*10**11

def colour(T):
    color=(-1)*2.5*math.log(radiance(4400,T)/radiance(5500,T))
    return color

t=numpy.arange(10,1000)
plt.plot(t,colour(t)
plt.show()
```

now i know that i can not pass a list to the above function colour. but it works when i pass a numpy array to function radiance it gives me a correct plot. however when i pass the array t to colour funtion it tells me error is due to radiance funtion which baffles me.

```
<ipython-input-105-0025fb9b0ac1> in radiance(l, T)
      1 def radiance(l,T):
      2     l=l*(10**(-`enter code here`10))
----> 3     const=2*h*pi*(c**2)
      4     const2=(h*c)/(k*T)
      5     d=expo(const2/l)-1
```

i tried to vectorize the second function but i get the same error

Comment: What type is T variable? Where do you instantiate variables `c` and `h`?

Comment: they are already defined in anther block of code

Comment: What type are these variables? I have to know that in order to provide help. I guess `c` is a list?

Comment: h,c,pi are floats representing plank const, speed of light and 3.14

Comment: Try to decompose your problem. It seems the function `radiance` work. So, in function `color`, set the two results of radiance in two variables and then build your color variable little by little. What is the result type of `radiance`, it is a float, right?

Comment: used numpy.log10 and it soved the problem thanks for advice